# how to separate tar.gz file to 5 files

Tags: linux, files, tar, split

we have huge file as

```
du -sh *

7.7G    HDP-2.6.5.0-centos7-rpm.tar.gz
```

and we want to separate the file to 5 files as

```
HDP1
HDP2
HDP3
HDP4
HDP5
```

and later I want to revert all `HDP*` to `HDP-2.6.5.0-centos7-rpm.tar.gz`

how to separate the file - `HDP-2.6.5.0-centos7-rpm.tar.gz`
to 5 files ?

the aim of this task is to transfer the files by network 
because if we transfer file that more then 5G , then we faced transferring problem

Comment: Look at the linked answers and `split -n` if you want a specific number of files rather than a maximum size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to look at the `split` command.

Comment: my example - split -b 1000M HDP-2.6.5.0-centos7-rpm.tar.gz "HDP"  , please add it to your answer